# Getuikit 3 sortable element on moved not triggered

Tags: vue.js, getuikit

For some reason I can't perform actions after the sortable elements are moved. The event UIkit.util.on('#sortable', 'moved', function (item) {}); is not being called/triggered.

The app is made with vue.js, but I get no error and every other uikit functionality works just fine. There are ~600 line of code so, I'll just show the ones that matter (I think).

```
<template>
  <div class="products">
    <MainMenu />
    <div id="ordering" uk-offcanvas="overlay: true">
        <div class="uk-offcanvas-bar" style="width:500px">
            <button class="uk-offcanvas-close" type="button" uk-close></button>
            <div>Drag to re-arrange the fields order<br><br>
            <ul id="sortable" class="uk-grid-small uk-child-width-1-1 uk-text-center" uk-sortable="handle: .uk-card" uk-grid>
              <li v-for="(data, idx) in computedData" :key="idx" :id="data.product_field_name">
                  <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-padding-small">{{data.product_field_name}}</div>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-default" uk-toggle="target: #ordering"><span uk-icon="move"></span> Field Ordering</button>

    <!-- REST OF HTML GOES HERE: FORMS, MODALS, ETC. -->

  </div>
</template>
<script>
UIkit.notification('test message','danger'); //THIS TRIGGERS OK

//UIKit ordering action - THIS DOES NOT
UIkit.util.on('#sortable', 'moved', function (item) {
  console.log('moved triggered');
});


// @ is an alias to /src
import MainMenu from "@/components/MainMenuEMVO.vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "products",
  components: {
    MainMenu
  },
  data() {
    return {
      add_dependency: {
        field: "",
        field_selection: ""
      },
      remove_dependency: {
        id: "",
        field_name: "",
        dependency_field: "",
        dependency_rule: "",
        dependency_value: "",
        enforcing_value: "",
      },
      productFields: "",
      lookupTables: "",
      dependencies: "",
      departments: "",
      search: "",
      computedFields: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        clearInterval(stateCheck);
        this.getProductsConfig();
      }
    }, 100);
  },
  computed: {...},
  methods: {
    getProductsConfig(){...},
    enableEdit(id){...},
    cancelEdit(id){...},
    submitEdit(id){...},
    addRule(id, field_name){...},
    removeDependency(fieldName, id){...}
  }
};
</script>
```

As mentioned before there are no errors or even warnings in console, so I really don't event know where to start looking at this.

Comment: you have it correct, so I assume the element is not present when you use UIkit.util.on ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem, so if anyone has the same issue:

Once I moved the code into the mounted() method of the vue.js it all works fine.

```
mounted() {
    //UIKit ordering action - THIS DOES NOT
    UIkit.util.on('#sortable', 'moved', function (item) {
      console.log('moved triggered');
    });

    let stateCheck = setInterval(() => {
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        clearInterval(stateCheck);
        this.getProductsConfig();
      }
    }, 100);
  },
```

the `UIkit.notification` works fine, but I guess since the util is attached to event it has to be made available to vue on startup.

Answer (score 0):

If you added UIkit as `<script src="./src/js/uikit.min.js"></script>` in your index.html then you can't use it inside Vue as expected, instead do:

```
npm i --save uikit
```

then in your Component

```
import UIkit from "uikit";
```

after that you can use everywhere

```
methods: {
  alertOnClick(msg) {
      UIkit.notification(msg, "danger");
    }
  }
}
```